# Digital signing certificate for SOAP

Tags: openssl, web-applications, x509, soap, digital-signatures

I'm calling a third-party Web Service with SOAP requests. This service requires me to to sign my SOAP requests digitally. Regarding to [How to buy a X.509 certificate for signing digital payloads](https://serverfault.com/questions/628122/how-to-buy-a-x-509-certificate-for-signing-digital-payloads) question, I bought an Email Signing Certificate from Entrust.

I got the private key from Entrust in `.p12` format. I used Windows Certificate Manager to extract the public key from it. I delivered this public key to my Web Service provider. I could not use the private key directly in `.p12`format in my program, so I used openssl to convert it to `.pem` format. Strictly speaking, I used this kind of command: `openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.key.pem -nocerts -nodes`.

I use converted private key, public key and passphrase to crate a signature to my SOAP request's header, however, the service is giving me an error "Security token failed to validate" when I send the request. I can't see any specific error as I can only see certificate data in the error.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Maybe the problem is related to my certificate. I found that my certificate's hashing algorithm is SHA-256 although my SOAP client only supports SHA-1 as well as the third-party service provider.

Comment: For me this is not certificate error, but web service error (with kind of authentication token)

Comment: A little bit more detailed error is this: "Security token failed to validate. weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.SecurityTokenValidateResult@61d76aac[status: false]". After that line I can see data from my certificate in the same error, but it is not telling me what is wrong.

Comment: This seems like WebLogic timeout case: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24902_01/doc.91/e24286/trblshoot.htm#EOTMA166

Comment: The interesting thing is that the [msg] tag contains information about my certificate and there is no information about the timestamp.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: You can try to implement certificate with SHA-1 and to check if this is the problem. You can check LetsEncrypt to get free certificate (or use selfsigned one)